# expired data cannot be deleted automatically in TDengine

Tags: sql, tdengine

Based on the official documentation from [TDengine website](https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/taos-sql#management):

> KEEP is how long the data of the database is kept, the default is 3650 days (10 years), and the database will automatically delete the data expired;

I created a database using following SQL:  create database test keep 15. but I found the data older than 15 days still can be displayed by using select query.
Anyone knows why the expired data is not deleted automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out, the data file may contain both expired data and unexpired data, TDengine database won't delete the data file until all the data expired.